# Redeem history from a certain line to another

Tags: linux, ubuntu, debian

Hi i would just like to take from my x line in the history to the y line and send it in a .txt file so how could i do that ? (i searched in the man page but didn't find anything)
thanks for your help!
I tried some `$history[x-y]` an this did'nt work at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do that by using `history | sed -n '30,50p;'` if you wanted to get the 30-50th lines of your history.

And then piping that output to a file with

`history | sed -n '30,50p;' > output.txt`